# How to use Mongoose with a highly dynamic schema MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to change the schema of my DB. Right now it's like:

```
{
   "disp":[
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141109
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141110
        },
        {
            "quantity":1,
            "date":20141111
        }
    ]
}
```

"date" is unique and indexed.
A schema like this one have a BIG downside for me. I can't update "quantity" for multiple dates in an atomic way so I have to implement [Two Phase Commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) in my app.

I'm testing alternative schemas and I think this one would match my needs

```
{
   "disp":{
        "20141109": {
            "quantity":1
        },
        "20141110": {
            "quantity":1
        },
        "20141111": {
            "quantity":1
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can atomically update quantities for more than one date but I wonder how to manage this with a mongoose schema because dates can be added and removed in a highly dynamic way.
In the collection there will be a lot of document with quantities specified for different dates
ex. a document can have quantities only for a few dates and another document can have quantities for a couple of years

Is is better to add/remove fields forcing every document to have a date field (default to 0 quantity) or is it better to set [strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) to false?
Are there any downsides I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Your second schema format is invalid. Arrays can hold only documents or values. Did you mean `disp:{...}` ?

Comment: @BatScream yes, I copied and pasted without double checking. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: You can't perform aggregate operations based on the dates if you have the second format. Preferably do not have anything that is dynamically variable and which could potentially be used in query selectors as keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with the second format, then it' best to use [Mixed Schema Type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) for your `disp` field:

```
var my_schema = new Schema({ disp: {} });
```

or

```
var my_schema = new Schema({ disp: Schema.Types.Mixed });
```

---

> Is is better to add/remove fields forcing every document to have a
>   date field (default to 0 quantity)?

It's not a very good idea, because you'll need to explicitly specify all possible dates inside your schema.

> or is it better to set strict to false?

I wouldn't advise doing so, because it'll affect the whole schema, not only `dist` field.

> Are there any downsides I'm not aware of?

Here are some downsides I can see:

- you'll loose all advantages of having a schema on a `dist` field;
- it'll be impossible to create an index on `dist` field;
- you won't be able to perform [`aggregate` operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) based on dates (thanx to BatScream).

But it doesn't mean that your idea is bad. Advantages of using dates as keys may overcome all disadvantages.